# STR_TO_DATE to replace non english month names

Tags: mysql

In my table on *MySQL database* I need update the column `sDate` ( *Date* ) with the value of column `sHour` ( *varchar* ).

I have tried this sql query :

```
UPDATE IGNORE `doTable`
SET `sDate` = STR_TO_DATE(`sHour`, '%d-%M-%Y')
WHERE
    `sDate` IS NULL;
```

And the output is :

```
+-----------+------------+
| sHour     | sDate      |
+-----------+------------+
| 01-ago-18 | NULL       |
| 01-apr-18 | 2018-04-01 |
| 01-feb-18 | 2018-02-01 |
| 01-gen-18 | NULL       |
| 01-giu-18 | NULL       |
| 01-mar-18 | 2018-03-01 |
| 01-nov-18 | 2018-11-01 |
| 01-ott-18 | NULL       |
| 01-set-18 | NULL       |
| 02-ago-18 | NULL       |
+-----------+------------+
10 rows in set
```

The problem is when the row `sHour` not contains the **Month name** in english ( en_US ).

For example the row :

```
+-----------+------------+
| sHour     | sDate      |
+-----------+------------+
| 01-ago-18 | NULL       |
+-----------+------------+
```

Is not update because the **Month name** ( *first three letters* ) is `ago` ( it_IT ) and not `aug` ( en_US ).

Instead the row :

```
+-----------+------------+
| sHour     | sDate      |
+-----------+------------+
| 01-apr-18 | 2018-04-01 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Is update because the **Month name** `-apr-` ( *first three letters* ) coincides on Italian and English language.

I have tried withous success this :

```
SET lc_time_names = 'it_IT';
```

How to do resolve this ?

Comment: Why don't you normalize such data? What if there are ambiguous values which could translate to multiple, different dates?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for reply, normalize ? how to do ?

Comment: @NicoHaase if his example is just a simple example of a complex datatabase it's not that easy to just "normalize all the data"

Comment: Well, according to the documentation, `STR_TO_DATE` does not use the configuration you've set through `lc_time_names`. "Normalization" could mean that you convert all existing data to the english format and no longer use the italian format

Comment: @NicoHaase Okay but the column to converting to english date is a string ... and for this conversion I have used `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: Yes, but that string won't be parsed by `STR_TO_DATE` as it cannot parse `01-ago-18`as this is not a proper date in english format

Comment: Solved Thank you with @Hamamelis reply.

Comment: Why don't you just ... show the example of "normalization"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in MYSQL.
I hope I was helpful.

```
UPDATE `doTable`
SET `sDate` = NULL;

UPDATE IGNORE `doTable`
SET `sDate` = STR_TO_DATE(`sHour`, '%d-%M-%Y')
WHERE
    `sDate` IS NULL;

UPDATE `doTable` jjj
JOIN (
    SELECT
        STR_TO_DATE(`sMonth`, '%d-%M-%Y') AS `xDate`
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                CASE
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('ago') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'aug',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('dic') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'dec',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('gen') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'jan',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('giu') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'jun',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('ott') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'oct',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('set') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'sep',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('lug') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'jul',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 2),
                '-',
                1
            ) IN ('mag') THEN
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-', 1),
                    '-',
                    'may',
                    '-',
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sHour`, '-' ,- 1)
                )
            END AS `sMonth`
        FROM
            `doTable`
        WHERE
            `sDate` IS NULL
        ) AS ttt
) AS kkk
SET jjj.`sDate` = kkk.`xDate`
WHERE
    jjj.`sDate` IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Hamamelis ! This is a great help !